# Step sensor doesn't count in the textview (in fragment)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-sensors

I've been doing one project on android studio (using kotlin) using fragment. I'm planning to implement a step sensor in another fragment but it didn't work and didn't have error also. I don't know where is the error. The sensor seems good but the steps didn't be counted in the text view. I put the code for the sensor in the fragment class. Anyone can help me? The app didn't crash and didn't tell where is the error just the number of steps didn't be counted

**This is the code for Fragment Class**

```
package com.androiddevs.runningappyt.ui.fragments
import android.content.Context.SENSOR_SERVICE
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.androiddevs.runningappyt.R
import com.androiddevs.runningappyt.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel
import com.androiddevs.runningappyt.ui.viewmodels.AppUtils
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_steps.*
import java.util.*
import com.androiddevs.runningappyt.core.SharedPreferencesManager
@AndroidEntryPoint
class StepsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_steps),SensorEventListener
{
private var isStarted = false
private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
private var stepCounter = 0
private var counterSteps = 0
private var stepDetector = 0
private var startDate: Date? = null
private var endDate: Date? = null


companion object{
    fun newInstance() = StepsFragment()
    const val TAG = "StepsFragment"}
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_steps, stepsContainer, false)
}
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)l

    sensorManager = context?.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

    // load previous status if any
    SharedPreferencesManager.instance.loadStartDate(startDate)
     SharedPreferencesManager.instance.loadInitialStepCount(counterSteps)

    Log.d(TAG, "startDate = $startDate")
    Log.d(TAG, "counterSteps = $counterSteps")

    if (startDate != null) {
        isStarted = true
    }

    initUI()
    bindUI()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (this.isStarted) {
        startService()
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    stopService()
}

override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "accuracy = $accuracy")
}

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
    when (event.sensor.type) {
        Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR -> {
            stepDetector++
        }
        Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER -> {
            if (counterSteps < 1) {
                counterSteps = event.values[0].toInt()
              SharedPreferencesManager.instance.saveInitialStepCount(counterSteps)
            }
            stepCounter = event.values[0].toInt() - counterSteps
        }
    }
    tv_step_count.text = "$stepCounter"
}

private fun initUI() {
    startDate?.let {
        tv_start_time.text = getString(R.string.start_time, AppUtils.getFormattedDate(it))
    } ?: run {
        tv_start_time.text = getString(R.string.start_time, "-")
    }

    tv_end_time.text = getString(R.string.end_time, "-")
    tv_step_count.text = "$stepCounter"

    if (this.isStarted) {
        btn_start.text = getString(R.string.stop)
    } else {
        btn_start.text = getString(R.string.start)
    }
}

private fun bindUI() {
    btn_start.setOnClickListener {
        if (this.isStarted) {
            stopCounter()
            btn_start.text = getString(R.string.start)
        } else {
            startCounter()
            btn_start.text = getString(R.string.stop)
        }
    }
}

private fun startService() {
    val stepsSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

    if (stepsSensor == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Step Counter Sensor !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        sensorManager?.registerListener(this, stepsSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
    }
}

private fun stopService() {
    sensorManager?.unregisterListener(this)
}

private fun startCounter() {
    isStarted = true
    this.stepCounter = 0
    this.stepDetector = 0
    this.counterSteps = 0

    // reset UI
    initUI()

    startDate = Date()
    startDate?.let {
        tv_start_time.text =
            getString(R.string.start_time, AppUtils.getFormattedDate(it))
     SharedPreferencesManager.instance.saveStartDate(it)
    }

    startService()
}

private fun stopCounter() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopCounter")
    isStarted = false
    endDate = Date()
    endDate?.let {
        tv_end_time.text =
            getString(R.string.end_time, AppUtils.getFormattedDate(it))
    }
    stopService()
   SharedPreferencesManager.instance.clear()
}}
```

**This is the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".ui.MainActivity"
  android:id="@+id/stepsContainer">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/start"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_start_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_start"
    tools:text="@string/start_time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_end_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_start_time"
    tools:text="@string/end_time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_step_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_end_time"
    tools:text="0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

the possibility solution is using `MutableLiveData()`.

> > **and how it's works?**

`MutableLiveData()` has `observe()` method that can be notified on every state change.

see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016896/how-to-update-textview-whenever-changes-happen-in-arraylist-in-kotlin) to see the example how to implement it

Comment: How should I replace the Array?

Comment: MutableLiveData can be used in any various datatype or data classes

Comment: Have you use MVVM pattern?? 
it shold be different class to create sensor logic and it will run with job manager, thats mean your sensor will continously run even you leave the activity. and you can stop everytime you need

Comment: the pattern will be : 

your sensor logic that returns data >> viewModel >>  activity that creating a new job.

Comment: Yeah I'm using MVVM!! Looks like you know how to do it . Can you help me?? I've been working on it for past couple of weeks 

Comment: How can I contact you? I'm new in kotlin and MVVM

Comment: Hadisyah, if you can give me your email and communicate there, I'll very appreciate that!

Comment: okay. you can find easily contact me on whatsapp wa.me/62895807400020